# UITabBarController disappears when pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have an app with a UITabBar and a NavigationController. When I use pushViewController the new ViewController appears with the NavigationController and the back button, but the UITabBarController disappears. I know there are lots of questions here about the same, but any of them have solved my question, maybe because I dont understand the answers given.

Any suggestion?

```
    ActivityViewController *activityController = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:activityController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you push your next viewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because Your rootViewController (for your main UIWindow) is set to a Navigationcontroller instead of your TabBar.
If you don't want the Tabbar to go away just set it as your root view controller

Do the following in appDidFinishLaunching in your AppDelegate

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *loginNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] loginViewController];
[firstViewController release];

self.window.rootViewController = loginNavigationController;
```

Then in your Login Page:

```
- (void)loginSuccessfull
{
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithViewController:firstViewController];
    [firstViewController release];

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithViewController:secondViewController];
    [secondViewController release];


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController, nil]];

    [firstNavigationController release];
    [secondNavigationController release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController];
    [tabBarController release];
```

}

If you still need the navigation functionality just wrap your viewControllers inside a UINavigationController, and add the serounding navigationController to the tabBar, instead of the UIViewcontroller

Comment: How can I set the TabBar to be the rootController?

Comment: Ok, but I dont have the tabBar at the start. I have a login view and then the tabBarController. Any suggestion to arrange this?

Comment: LoginViewcontroller would become your rootViewController, after a successful login initialize the tabbar, and navigate to it, by calling pushViewController:tabBar

Comment: ok, that is what i am actually doing,but having the navigationcontroller as the rootController. But when I push my tabBar I can also press a cell of a tableView and push it, and there is where my tabBar disappears...

Comment: And also, how can I navigate to the tabBar with pushViewController:tabBar if my root controller is LoginViewcontroller? I dont have any NavigationController...

Comment: Wrap your loginViewController in a navigationController

Comment: call pushViewController:animated on self.navigationController, The new questions are not related to the original post, you should keep them separated and start new threads.